# Assembly reference for Kinect Toolbox in Visual Studio

Tags: kinect, toolbox

I have downloaded the KinectToolbox from the codeplex website and added Kinect.Toolbox.dll into the reference in my project, but when I put "using Kinect.Toolbox" I get the error "The type or namespace "Toolbox" does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Samples.Kinect' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Any suggestions?

Comment: That is strange. I would understand, if the compiler would say "The type or namespace name 'Kinect' could not be found". Can you show your code?

Comment: This is not my area of expertise, but you can try to build your project, and see if that solves your problem. Sometimes it does.